# Is binary mapping of simple stationary series still stationary

Tags: time-series, binary-data, stationarity

Suppose I have a weakly stationary series with a support $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. If I were to map all values of this series into a binary series with support $\{0,1\}$ using the rule $\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0\}$, $\{2,3\}\rightarrow\{1\}$, would the resulting binary series still be (weakly) stationary? Intuitively the answer would seem to be yes since this is just a "coarsening" of the series and not an alteration of its statistical properties, but how do I show this?

Comment: You just asked essentially the same question and [one of the replies there shows the answer is no.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/411450/919)  The relationship between the questions is that you can shift all the distributions by $-3/2$ and in so doing your mapping is affinely equivalent to the absolute value function.  It looks, therefore, like you will get much more out of that reply by studying it further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that's not quite true. The mapping I propose here cannot be accomplished by the absolute value of a linear transformation. That would only be the case if the rule were $\{1,2\}\rightarrow\{0\}$, $\{0,3\}\rightarrow\{1\}$. In all honesty, though, I didn not see how the parametrization argument in the comment you referenced worked. I understood the intuition, but it still did not show that the new series could lack stationarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide a counterexample, I will emulate [an example described by Yves in responding to a similar inquiry.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/411450/919)

Consider this family of distributions $p$ on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ parameterized by $p\in[0,1/4]:$

$$\left\{\eqalign{p(0) &= p \\ p(1) &= \frac{3}{4}-3p \\ p(2)&=3p \\ p(3)&=\frac{1}{4}-p.}\right.$$

**These are all the distributions with mean $3/2$ and variance $1/2.$**  (We knew *a priori* that such a family ought to exist because such distributions are determined by four probabilities but are subject to just three linear constraints, including the sum-to-unity constraint required of all probability distributions.)

For $p\approx 0$ most of the probability is concentrated on the value $1,$ with some placed near $3$ to maintain the mean and variance, while for $p\approx 1/4$ the distribution has been inverted and now concentrates on the value $2,$ with most of the rest of the probability placed near the value $0.$  This is evident in the first figure below, where $p$ grows from $0$ to $1/4$ as time goes on.

Thus, any sequence of parameters $p_i$ determines a sequence $X_i$ of independent random variables with corresponding distributions $p_i.$ This sequence is weakly second-order stationary because the mean and variance are constant while independence assures the covariances are constantly zero.

[image: ![Figure 1: Realization of X]

*This figure shows one realization of $(X_i)$ corresponding to $p_i$ increasing linearly from $0$ to $1/4.$*  The heights have been randomly jittered to resolve overlaps. The curve is a Loess smooth tracing out a local mean; as intended, it is essentially flat, indicating first-order weak stationarity.

Under the mapping in the question ($f(0)=f(1)=0;\ f(2)=f(3)=1$) the new distribution assigns probability $p + 3/4-3p = 3/4-2p$ to $0$ and the remaining probability $1/4+2p$ to $1.$  The mean of this distribution is $1/4+2p,$ whence the means of the $f(X_i)$ form a sequence $(1/4 + 2p_i).$  If the $p_i$ are not constant, then $f(X_i)$ is not even weakly first order stationary.

[image: ![Figure 2: Series f(X)]

*The same series, as transformed by $f.$  The Loess smooth demonstrates the lack of stationarity.*

#### Appendix: The Code

This is the `R` code used to generate the figures.  It shows how to create realizations of $X_t$ and $f(X_t).$

```
#
# Sample from the distributional family.
#
r <- function(p, n=1) {
  p <- min(1/4, max(0, p)) 
  sample(0:3, n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(p, 3/4-3*p, 3*p, 1/4-p))
}
#
# Transform the values.
#
f <- function(x) floor(x/2)
#
# Simulate a process from an array of parameters (p).
#
n <- 300
# p <- seq(0, 1/4, length.out=n)
p <- rep(0:1/4, each=floor(n/2)) # An extreme example
x <- sapply(p, r)
#
# Plot (X) and (f(X)).
#
library(ggplot2)
plot.it <- function(var="x", title="Series X") {
  ggplot(X, aes_string("t", var)) + 
    geom_smooth(method="loess") + 
    geom_jitter(aes(fill=X), shape=21, alpha=0.5, width=0, height=0.05) +
    ggtitle(title)
}
X <- data.frame(t=1:n, p=p, x=x, y=f(x), X=factor(x))
plot.it()
plot.it("y", "Series f(X)")
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the incredibly detailed response and for those beautiful plots! I completely see now that a stationary mean and variance from the original series does not guarantee the same for the binary series. I still have one question about the parameterization, however. Does the change in the parameter $p$ cause the original series to no longer be stationary since $Cov(Y_t,Y_{t+i})$ changes with $t$? If the third condition for weak stationarity were considered would this counterexample still hold?

Comment: Because the $X_t$ are independent, $\operatorname{Cov}(X_s,X_t)=0$ whenever $s\ne t.$  I don't know what you mean by the "third condition for weak stationarity."  If you are referring to third-order weak stationarity, that indeed would rule out this counterexample--but the same technique would yield counterexamples for random variables supported on sets of five or more points. I suspect one could even construct counterexamples (with continuous distributions) where *all* moments are stationary, because equality of moments does not assure equality of distribution.

Comment: Sorry, that was a dumb question. I understand completely now. I can't thank you enough for your great comment!